# Django FileNotFound Error after Deployment on GCE

Tags: python, django, linux, django-views, django-filebrowser

I'm working on a Django 2 project in which I have an `img` folder inside my root directory and I'm saving some images into this folder then create a zip archive from this folder and send to the browser. It was working fine on my local system but when I have deployed it on a Liux Instance on Google Compute Engine using Gunicorn, it returns an error for this repository.

Here's my **views.py**

```
class PerformImgSegmentation(generics.ListAPIView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    img_url = self.kwargs.get('encoded_url')
    print(img_url)
    print('get request')

    def create_pascal_label_colormap():
        colormap = np.zeros((256, 3), dtype=int)
        ind = np.arange(256, dtype=int)

        for shift in reversed(range(8)):
            for channel in range(3):
                colormap[:, channel] |= ((ind >> channel) & 1) << shift
            ind >>= 3

        return colormap

    def label_to_color_image(label):
        if label.ndim != 2:
            raise ValueError('Expect 2-D input label')

        colormap = create_pascal_label_colormap()

        if np.max(label) >= len(colormap):
            raise ValueError('label value too large.')

        return colormap[label]

    def vis_segmentation(image, seg_map):
        seg_image = label_to_color_image(seg_map).astype(np.uint8)

        # BasicSource Modification in the original Image for segmentation
        imgOrigin = cv2.imread('originImage.png')
        seg_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(seg_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(seg_image_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        # Creating the Mask of the Image via Segmentation Map
        cv2.imwrite('MaskedImage.png', seg_image)
        maskedImage = cv2.bitwise_and(imgOrigin, imgOrigin, mask=im_bw)
        # Generating the transparent image on the base of Masked Image.
        outputImgAlpha = cv2.cvtColor(maskedImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        bg_color = outputImgAlpha[0][0]
        maskNew = np.all(outputImgAlpha == bg_color, axis=2)
        outputImgAlpha[maskNew] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        image_bgr_transparent = cv2.cvtColor(outputImgAlpha, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGRA)
        cv2.imwrite('ExtractedImage.png', image_bgr_transparent)

        # #################### END of PROCESSING MODIFICATION ##########################
        unique_labels = np.unique(seg_map)

    LABEL_NAMES = np.asarray([
        'background', 'aeroplane', 'bicycle', 'bird', 'boat', 'bottle', 'bus',
        'car', 'cat', 'chair', 'cow', 'diningtable', 'dog', 'horse', 'motorbike',
        'person', 'pottedplant', 'sheep', 'sofa', 'train', 'tv'
    ])

    # @title Select and download models {display-mode: "form"}

    MODEL_NAME = 'mobilenetv2_coco_voctrainaug'  # @param ['mobilenetv2_coco_voctrainaug', 'mobilenetv2_coco_voctrainval', 'xception_coco_voctrainaug', 'xception_coco_voctrainval']

    _DOWNLOAD_URL_PREFIX = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/'
    _MODEL_URLS = {
        'mobilenetv2_coco_voctrainaug':
            'deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_29.tar.gz',
        'mobilenetv2_coco_voctrainval':
            'deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_trainval_2018_01_29.tar.gz',
        'xception_coco_voctrainaug':
            'deeplabv3_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_04.tar.gz',
        'xception_coco_voctrainval':
            'deeplabv3_pascal_trainval_2018_01_04.tar.gz',
    }
    _TARBALL_NAME = 'deeplab_model.tar.gz'

    model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(model_dir)

    download_path = os.path.join(model_dir, _TARBALL_NAME)
    print('downloading model, this might take a while...')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(_DOWNLOAD_URL_PREFIX + _MODEL_URLS[MODEL_NAME],
                               download_path)
    print('download completed! loading DeepLab model...')

    MODEL = DeepLabModel(download_path)
    print('model loaded successfully!')

    # @title Run on sample images {display-mode: "form"}

    SAMPLE_IMAGE = ''  # @param ['image1', 'image2', 'image3']

    # ENTER YOUR IMAGE URL
    IMAGE_URL = img_url  # @param {type:"string"}

    _SAMPLE_URL = ('https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/'
                   'deeplab/g3doc/img/%s.jpg?raw=true')

    def run_visualization(url):
        """Inferences DeepLab model and visualizes result."""
        try:
            f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            jpeg_str = f.read()
            original_im = Image.open(BytesIO(jpeg_str))
        except IOError:
            print('Cannot retrieve image. Please check url: ' + url)
            return

        print('running deeplab on image %s...' % url)
        resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(original_im)
        originImgArray = np.array(resized_im)
        originalBGRImage = cv2.cvtColor(originImgArray, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imwrite('originImage.png', originalBGRImage)

        vis_segmentation(resized_im, seg_map)
        print('Foreground Extraction is Done... check ExtractedImage.png file')

    image_url = IMAGE_URL or _SAMPLE_URL % SAMPLE_IMAGE
    run_visualization(image_url)
    # Genearte a Zip archive which Includes all images

    filelist = ["img/ExtractedImage.png", "img/MaskedImage.png"]

    byte_data = BytesIO()
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(byte_data, "w")

    for file in filelist:
        filename = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file))
        zip_file.write(file, filename)
    zip_file.close()

    response = HttpResponse(byte_data.getvalue(), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=files.zip'

    # Print list files in zip_file
    zip_file.printdir()

    return response
```

And here's the error it returns:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/http://i.imgur.com/tSYZBuU.jpg/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/root/ImgSegEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ImgSeg/Imgseg/views.py", line 189, in get
    zip_file.write(file, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1581, in write
    zinfo = ZipInfo.from_file(filename, arcname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 482, in from_file
    st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'img/ExtractedImage.png'
```

Even I have set up the permissions for `img` folder by running this command:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w img
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open the files in the current working directory because you didn't specify a path. You need to use an absolute path instead:

```
import os
from PROJECT import settings

filelist = [os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'img/ExtractedImage.png'),
            os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'img/MaskedImage.png')]
```

This will get the absolute path of `img` directory.